# How to validate children component where the submit button is in the parent component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a **parent component: PersonalInfo.tsx** and a **child component: WorkExperience.tsx**. There will be multiple child components inside of the parent component.

**Parent Component: PersonalInfo.tsx**

```
export default function PersonalInfo() {
  const [name, nameDispatch] = useReducer(nameReducer, {
    name: "",
    error: null,
  });

  const [workExperiences, setWorkExperiences] = useState([
    generateEmptyWorkExperience(),
    generateEmptyWorkExperience(),
  ]);

  function handleWorkExperienceChange(
    index: number,
    workExperience: WorkExperience
  ) {
    const newWorkExperiences = [...workExperiences];
    newWorkExperiences[index] = workExperience;
    setWorkExperiences(newWorkExperiences);
  }

  function handleSubmit(event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("Submit", name);
    nameDispatch({ type: "handleCheck" });
  }
  return (
    <>
      <div>Personal Info</div>
      <form
        style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column" }}
        onSubmit={handleSubmit}
      >
        <label>
          Name:
          <input
            type="text"
            name="name"
            value={name.name}
            onChange={(e) =>
              nameDispatch({ type: "handleChange", name: e.target.value })
            }
          />
          {name.error && <div style={{ color: "red" }}>{name.error}</div>}
        </label>
        <label>
          Email:
          <input type="email" name="email" />
        </label>
        {workExperiences.map((workExperience, index) => (
          <WorkExperience
            key={index}
            company={workExperience.company}
            startDate={workExperience.startDate}
            endDate={workExperience.endDate}
            onChange={handleWorkExperienceChange}
            index={index}
          />
        ))}

        <button
          onClick={() =>
            setWorkExperiences([
              ...workExperiences,
              generateEmptyWorkExperience(),
            ])
          }
        >
          Add Work Experience
        </button>

        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </>
  );
}
```

I am using useReducer to manages state for input field in **child component: WorkExperience.tsx**. In each reducer, there is a function that validates the input.

For example, **CompanyNameReducer**:

The company **state** has the company name and error. If there is any error, the error will be displayed at the bottom of the input field.

The company **action** has two type:

1. handleChange:
2. handleCheck: Check if the input is valid

```
interface CompanyState {
  name: string;
  error: string | null;
}

interface CompanyChangeAction {
  type: "handleChange";
  name: string;
}

interface CompanyAction {
  type: CompanyChangeAction | "handleCheck";
}

function companyReducer(
  state: CompanyState,
  action: CompanyChangeAction | CompanyAction
) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "handleChange":
      return {
        ...state,
        name: action.name,
      };
    case "handleCheck":
      if (!state.name) {
        return {
          ...state,
          error: "Name is required",
        };
      }
      return {
        ...state,
        error: null,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

**Child Component: WorkExperience.tsx**

```
export default function WorkExperience(props: WorkExperienceProps) {
  const [company, companyDispatch] = useReducer(companyReducer, {
    name: props.company,
    error: null,
  });

  const [date, dateDispatch] = useReducer(dateReducer, {
    startDate: props.startDate,
    endDate: props.endDate,
    error: null,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    props.onChange(props.index, {
      company: company.name,
      startDate: date.startDate,
      endDate: date.endDate,
    });
  }, [company, date]);

  return (
    <>
      <div>Work Experience {props.index + 1}</div>

      <label>
        Name:
        <input
          type="text"
          name="company"
          value={company.name}
          onChange={(e) =>
            companyDispatch({ type: "handleChange", name: e.target.value })
          }
        />
        {company.error && <div style={{ color: "red" }}>{company.error}</div>}
      </label>

      <label>
        Start Date:
        <input
          type="date"
          name="startDate"
          value={date.startDate ? date.startDate.format("YYYY-MM-DD") : ""} // Convert Dayjs object to string
          onChange={(e) =>
            dateDispatch({
              type: "handleStartDateChange",
              startDate: dayjs(e.target.value),
            })
          }
        />
      </label>

      <label>
        End Date:
        <input
          type="date"
          name="endDate"
          value={date.endDate ? date.endDate.format("YYYY-MM-DD") : ""} // Convert Dayjs object to string
          onChange={(e) =>
            dateDispatch({
              type: "handleEndDateChange",
              endDate: dayjs(e.target.value),
            })
          }
        />
        {date.error && <div style={{ color: "red" }}>{date.error}</div>}
      </label>
    </>
  );
}
```

**What I want to achieve:**

I want to trigger case 'handleCheck' in the **Child Component:** **WorkExperience.tsx** when submit button is clicked from the **Parent Component: PersonalInfo.tsx**

Here is the [Code SandBox Link](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/parent-child-form-submission-mw98wv?file=%2Fsrc%2FWorkExperience.tsx%3A18%2C25&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltqj0t5900063b6k2yf8ey88%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%252C0%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltqj0t5800023b6k1kk6r459%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltqj0t5800033b6kfoer57bp%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltqj0t5800053b6kh946t6vy%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B66.80348444347956%252C33.19651555652044%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522cltqj0t5800023b6k1kk6r459%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltqj0t5800023b6k1kk6r459%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltql6yqr00023b6ktfuzf9mf%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A18%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A25%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A18%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A25%257D%255D%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252FWorkExperience.tsx%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522cltql6yqr00023b6ktfuzf9mf%2522%257D%252C%2522cltqj0t5800053b6kh946t6vy%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltqj0t5800053b6kh946t6vy%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522cltqjpzlr01ln3b6kl18lkyts%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltqjpzlr01ln3b6kl18lkyts%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%2522cltqj0t5800033b6kfoer57bp%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltqj0t5800033b6kfoer57bp%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Afalse%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Afalse%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A0%257D)

I've come across similar questions where it was suggested to lift the child component state up to the parent. However, in my case, I'm not sure if this approach is suitable since there could be numerous child components.

Comment: The codesandbox link does not work. It seems either we don't  have access to the codesandbox or it has been deleted.

Comment: Lifting the state up to a common ancestor component is the common and sensical pattern to apply here. Also, just FYI, your sandbox link appears to be broken, and your base sandbox doesn't appear to exist or it isn't made public.

Comment: @santra72 My apologies. This is the updated link, it should work now [Code Sandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/parent-child-form-submission-mw98wv?file=%2Fsrc%2FWorkExperience.tsx)

Answer (score 1):

if i understand correctly, you are attempting to call validation logic in the child component(s) based on a submit event in the parent component.  if that is the case, an option would be handling both the validation logic and state management in the parent component, as well as storing error states.  the child could then simply display the state value and error passed down from the parent.  as Drew Reese commented, lifting the state up still makes sense here.
especially since you are already storing most of your state in the parent component and passing it down, i'm not sure what the benefit would be in allowing the child component to handle its own state as well, since you're tring to sync them all up.  you're even already passing onChange events up to the parent!  instead, the child's responsibilities could be display only.  for example:

```
const PersonalInfo = () => {
    const [workExperiences, setWorkExperiences] = useState([
        {id: 1, companyName: 'test1'},
        {id: 2, companyName: 'test2'},
    ]);
    const [workExperienceErrors, setWorkExperienceErrors] = useState(
        {id: 1},
        {id: 2},
    );
    const handleWorkExperienceChange = (id, name, value) => {
        setWorkExperiences(prevVals => ([
            ...prevVals.filter(x => x.id != id),
            {
                ...prevVals.find(x => x.id == id),
                [name]: value
            }
        ]))
        validateWorkExperience(id, name, value);
    }
    const validateWorkExperience = (id, name, value) => {
        // easy to validate any prop here
        if (name == 'companyName') {
            if (!value) {
                setError(id, name, 'Company name is required!')
            } else {
                clearError(id, name);
            }
        }
    }
    const setError = (id, name, errorMessage) => {
        setWorkExperienceErrors(prevVals => ([
            ...prevVals.filter(x => x.id != id),
            {
                ...prevVals.find(x => x.id == id),
                [name]: errorMessage
            }
        ]))
    }
    const clearError = (id, name) => {
        setWorkExperienceErrors(prevVals => {
            const selectedError = workExperienceErrors.find(x => x.id == id);
            delete selectedError[name];
            return [
                ...prevVals.filter(x => x.id != id),
                selectedError
            ];
        })
    }
    return (
        <div>
            {workExperiences.map(x => {
                const errorData = workExperienceErrors.find(err => err.id == x.id);
                return (
                    <WorkExperience
                        key={x.id}
                        data={x}
                        errorData={errorData}
                        onChange={handleWorkExperienceChange}
                    />
                )
            })}
        </div>
    )
}

const WorkExperience = ({ data, errorData, onChange }) => {
    const handleChange = (e) => {
        onChange(data.id, e.target.name, e.target.value);
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <label htmlFor="companyName">Company Name</label>
            <input id="companyName" name="companyName" value={data.companyName} />
            {errorData.companyName && (<div style={{ color: "red" }}>{errorData.companyName}</div>)}
        </div>
    )
}
```

a clunky example, but hopefully you get the idea.  as you can see, you're already doing a lot of this work in the parent component and it wouldn't be to different to fully commit to that.
you'll find this approach happening behind the scenes in libraries like 'react-form-hook':  top-level form component handling state/validation and passing it values/errors down to children which only display props and pass back onChange events.  sometimes using a context makes sense if you are concerned with passing loads of data through many layers of components.  either way, lift that state up!